# apn_for_rails gem implementation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I have the apn_for_rails gem installed and configured correctly, the problem I'm running into is probably a syntax problem due to my newness to Ruby on Rails.

I have this in /models under the file push_notification.rb

```
class ApnDevice < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

in routes.rb

```
match '/api/v2.0/RegisterIOSDevice',              :to => Api::V_2_0::ApiNotifications
```

and then I have another file in /lib/api/v_2_0 called api_notifications.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'apn_on_rails'

module Api
  module V_2_0
    class ApiPushNotification < sinatra::Base
      include ApplicationHelper
      include Api::V_2_0::ApiResponse
      include ApiUtil

      def push_notification(params)
        status = -1
        error = nil
        begin
          if params[:device_token].blank?
            return status_respnse(params,status,'device_token cant be blank')
          end
          existing_device_token = ApnDevice.find_by_token(params[:device_token])
          if existing_device_token
            return status_response(params,status,'Token already exists for device')
          end
          token = ApnDevice.create!(:token => params[:device_token])
        rescue Exception => e
          error = e.message
          Rails.logger.info "#{e.class} : #{e.message}"
          Rails.logger.info e.backtrace.join("\n")
        rescue => e
          error = e 
          Rails.logger.info "Caught exception: #{e}"
          Rails.logger.info e.backtrace.join("\n")
        end #end of rescue
        status_response(params,status,error)
      end
      get '/api/v2.0/RegisterIOSDevice.:format' do
        push_notification(params)
      end
      post '/api/v2.0/RegisterIosDevice.:format' do
        push_notification(params)
      end
    end #end of class ApiPushNotification
  end #end of module V_2_0
end #end of module Api
```

but it gives me this huge error when I run my server, I won't post the whole thing, but it says this basically

```
/lib/api/v_2_0/api_notifications.rb:7: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
/lib/api/v_2_0/api_notifications.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

this is followed by a stack trace which I will not post but I can't seem to find the problem, any ideas?

Edit:

ok I added the utf-8 suggestion, now I'm getting a new error:

```
lib/api/v_2_0/api_notifications.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing there, but why are you using Rails if you use Sinatra instead in lib?

To your error, add the following code at the first line:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: Good question, I'm just updating the existing Rails app so I don't know the answer to that. Which file do I put your code in? thanks for the help!

Comment: You should put it on the top of the file which have a error such, the one you've postet. api_notifications.rb

Comment: Ok cool, that got rid of the first error, what about the second one? it looks like I have too many ends, or not enough. I've tried to look for about an hour but it escapes me

Comment: the error is actually different now, I'll edit the question too
lib/api/v_2_0/api_notifications.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)